# Get data from an object and put it in a textbox

Tags: c#

I have an object which contains 2 pieces of information in `objData[0]`. The information is `System_ID` and `Network_ID`. The data is coming from a query to a database.

I want to get the data out of the object and display it in two separate text boxes, one for `system_ID` and one for `Network_ID`. Right now I am putting them into a combo box.

See below my code:

```
    //get network ID and systenm name
    private void cmbAddItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FASystems fSys = new FASystems(sConn);
        object objData =  fSys.getSystemNetworkIDFriendlyName(cmbAddItem.Text.ToString());
        cmbNetworkID.DataSource = objData;
        cmbNetworkID.DisplayMember = "Network_ID";
        cmbSysName.DataSource = objData;
        cmbSysName.DisplayMember = "System_Name";
        // txtNetworkID.Text = objData[0].Network_ID;
    }
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? This is a fairly basic stuff... Furthermore, why you use a type `object` to store values like this? Create a class for this purpose.

Comment: You are using an API of FA Systems. Don't they provide interfaces for working with their API?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your C# compiler is 3.0 or up use the var keyword on the api call

```
var objData =  fSys.getSystemNetworkIDFriendlyName(cmbAddItem.Text.ToString());
```

Let's assume you're correct that there is an array now in objData with a type in it that has at least Network_ID as a member...

```
txtNetworkID.Text = objData[0].Network_ID;
```

should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the function declaration for getSystemNetworkIDFriendlyName and show how you are populating the return type?

I recommend creating a new class to store the NetworkID and SystemID

```
class SystemInfo
{
   public string NetworkID { get; set; } 
   public string SystemId { get; set; } 
}
```

Rewrite the function getSystemNetworkIDFriendlyName to return an instance of SystemInfo. Then populating your textbox becomes:

```
 FASystems fSys = new FASystems(sConn);
 SystemInfo inf o=  fSys.getSystemNetworkIDFriendlyName(cmbAddItem.Text.ToString());
 txtNetworkID.Text = info.NetworkID;
```

Hope this helps,

KenC